# Importing Multiple Tables from Excel Using SSIS 2008 - Skipping Rows with ADO.Net Source

Tags: excel, sql-server-2008, ssis

I have created a SSIS 2008 Package which imports rows from a spreadsheet. I need to start on row 4 so I have used the OpenRowset property of the Excel connection manager.

However, I need to import multiple tables. Can this be done with the Excel Connection Manager?

I believe it can be done with an ADO.Net Source, but I don't know how to skip rows using that.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

any way you can add a rownumber on your datasource? then as you pull data from your datasource in SSIS, you can conditonally split on rownumber < 4

Comment: Agreed. Then send the first 4 rows to the trash destination http://www.konesans.com/products/trash-destination.aspx

Comment: Are you asking me to add a column for Row Number in the Spreadsheet?